Lithium batteries
Are all lithium batteries required by law to have a built in management system to stop them overheating and going on fire? If not why not?
The reason I‘m asking is hand luggage which is permitted to carry certain dangerous goods like lithium batteries/ power banks, vapes, lighters etc are sometimes at the gate checked in as hold luggage because there is no more space in the cabin bins of a plane. Yet these bags are not rescreened and passengers are not always reminded to remove these items. So they pose a fire risk in the hold if they haven’t got overheating protection. I think this is a lapse in safety….maybe somebody can enlighten me of the regulations. Thank-you for your time…

This was closed on SE Travel, and follows from SE Travel Are gate-checked bags screened for items not allowed in the hold? The OP asks here about regulations, so IDK why this is a VTC as being "opinion".

A management system can fail, so there is still some risk of fire even with one. As ever the goal in safety is not to totally eliminate risk, which is impossible, but to reduce the risk to some level (once per billion hours, say) that we are comfortable with. Presumably the chance of this specific scenario happening is small enough that regulators are not concerned with it.

If you're asking about existing regulations, you should specify the jurisdiction.

And "if not why not?" is not likely to be a question we can answer objectively. Unless the regulating organization publishes their internal discussions, it's hard to know why they chose not to regulate something.

Are you asking whether [tag:any-jurisdiction] has regulations on the manufacture, sale or use of "lithium" batteries?  (Presumably lithion-ion, since lithium-air batteries are quite stable).  Perhaps you should restrict your question geographically or by activity.

I'm hesitant to say there is no legal requirement to have a thermal management system, but there likely are no legal requirements to have such systems.
There are independent safety organizations such as UL that require things like overcharge and thermal protections in order to receive a UL certification.
I can tell you with absolute certainty that most of the off brand tool batteries you can buy online do not have thermal protections and are legal to sell in the US.
I feel like the "why not" question is so subjective it's almost unanswerable, but to take a stab at it where do you draw the line?  Traditional lead acid batteries (car batteries) can cause a tremendously dangerous explosion if they overheat.  Are you concerned about protections on them?  The propane tank on your grill would create a devastating explosion if it overheats, do we need to add a computer system to them to prevent this?
Laws that aim to enforce safety features typically originate from catastrophe and/or clear evidence of efficacy, and are evaluated based on cost.  Millions of people died from falling down the stairs before strict codes on stair construction were ever even considered.  There just really aren't that many deaths from cell phone battery fires.  The efficacy of said systems is also questionable.  All phones have thermal protection logic in place and yet some of them still catch fire, usually as a result of physical damage but not always (looking at you Note 7).
There is an estimated 2.8 terawatt hours of lithium ion batteries in use today.  The average cell phone battery is 9-18 watt hours.  Assuming it costs $1 per 13.5 watt hours to bring all batteries in the world up to this proposed guideline it would cost roughly $207,407,407,407.41.  There are roughly 25,578 commercial airplanes in service today.  You could spend that money on $8.1 million worth of safety equipment per plane and probably make a significantly bigger impact.  Since lithium batteries are able to catch fire even with the safety systems perhaps it would make more sense to design the cargo areas to be able to jettison from the aircraft with a button in the event of a fire?  I'm sure that would be doable with $8 million.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No, they are not. Raw lithium batteries are allowed in the US. Thermal management is not required even in installed products.
But FAA regulations do require you to remove them from the carry on bags being put in cargo while plane side.
https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/portable-electronic-devices-with-batteries

Spare (uninstalled) lithium metal and lithium ion batteries are always prohibited in checked baggage and must be placed in carry-on. When a carry-on bag is checked at the gate or at planeside, any spare lithium batteries must be removed from the bag and kept with the passenger in the aircraft cabin.

Just because the flight attendants don't do it doesn't mean it's not against the law.
